# Cree una cadena de conexion en variable. ¿Como lo utilizo ahora?

Tags: asp.net

no estoy seguro de como hacer esto posible, así que me gustaría algún consejo ya que soy nuevo manejando conexiones en este lenguaje.

En mi código utilizo la siguiente cadena para conectarme a SQL SERVER;

WEB.Config

```
 <connectionStrings>
  <add name="Primaria" connectionString="Data Source=LAPTOP- 
   DDBTHB5L\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DEMO;Integrated Security=SSPI"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

.CS

```
   private string connectionString = 
   WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Primaria"].ConnectionString;
```

Mi problema ahora es que desarrolle una nueva cadena de conexión y lo almacena en una variable llamada scon.

//parte del código

```
 protected void cadena(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 

      //
      //
      //


               Servidor = dr["Servidor"].ToString();
                BD = dr["Nombre_BD"].ToString();
            }
        }
        dr.Close();
        string constr = "Data Source ="+Servidor+"; Initial Catalog ="+BD+"; Integrated Security = SSPI";

        Session["scon"] = scon;


}
```

¿Como utilizo ahora la nueva que definí en el siguiente código?, ya que ocupo las 2, y de la manera que esta ahora solo me conecta al de web.config.

```
{


    string SQLFamilia = "SELECT Nombre from Alumnos"; ;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQLAlumnos, con);
    SqlDataReader reader;
```

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. Si al crear la conexion usas `connectionString`, usará la conexión que tienes definida en el web.config. Para usar la nueva, tendras que crear la conexión con `SqlConnection con2=new SqlConnection((string)Session["scon"]);` no?

Comment: Asi es, tal y como indicas quiero utilizar esta nueva y no la del web.config xD

Comment: Así como te indico Pikoh debes de intentarlo.

Comment: @KJSK lo recomendable segun mi experiencia es colocar en web config la conexion e incriptada porque imaginate al momento de nose cambiar algo tendra que cambiar y compilar y publicar nuevamente y seria algo tedioso por eso si lo colocas en web.config no necesita compilar sino cambiar la ruta y listo. es un comentario.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes Agregar de forma dinámica un CNN String a tu `WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings`, lo cual luego puedes leerlo durante la ejecución del programa (el archivo **webconfig** no se modifica).

```
Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(null);
config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings.Add(new ConnectionStringSettings("mycustonstringName","mycustonstringValue"));
```

Luego simplemente lo recuperas como si estuvieses leyendo del webconfig.

```
var myCustomCnnString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mycustonstringName"].ConnectionString;
```